# I made Class Object inherit Class Turtle. Getting AttributeError

Tags: python, class, inheritance, turtle-graphics, attributeerror

I made a separate python file to create the object class. Than I imported this class to another file and made this pad1 object.

```
pad1 = Object("square", "blue", -350, 0)
pad1.shapesize(stretch_len=1,stretch_wid=5)
```

But I am getting an error saying: 'Object' object has no attribute '_outlinewidth'

Object Class code

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle


class Object(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, shape, color, x, y):
        self = Turtle()
        self.speed(0)
        self.shape(shape)
        self.color(color)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(x, y)
```

How can I solve this issue? I want to solve this problem using separate files and using classes, similar to the way I have tried it

Comment: `super().__init__() ` rather than `self = Turtle()`. See [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) and [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

Answer (score 1):

@Rabbid76 is correct (+1), below is a rework of your code incorporating the comment and tweaking some other issues:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Pad(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, shape, color, position):
        super().__init__(shape=shape, visible=False)

        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color(color)
        self.penup()
        self.setposition(position)
        self.showturtle()

pad1 = Pad('square', 'blue', (-350, 0))
pad1.shapesize(stretch_len=1, stretch_wid=5)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```